# Android Braintree SDK Integration in current application's activity

Tags: android, braintree

I would like to integrate `Braintree API` into my android application.I referred to [Braintree](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/android+ruby/start/hello-client) page and I got an idea for how we can integrate it into application. But I have an issue when I want to display `Drop-In UI` below of my currently showing activity's layout. But in demo it will start new activity `BraintreePaymentActivity.java`.

I don't want to open new activity I just want to show the same operation in my activity. For that I refer [Card-form demo](https://github.com/braintree/android-card-form) and added my custom button for Purchase.And on Purchase button click I call below code. But here I don't understand **from where I can get `Nonce` value?**

```
Braintree.setup ( this, CLIENT_TOKEN_FROM_SERVER, new Braintree.BraintreeSetupFinishedListener () {
 @Override
 public void onBraintreeSetupFinished ( boolean setupSuccessful, Braintree braintree, String errorMessage, Exception exception ) {
    if ( setupSuccessful ) {
        // braintree is now setup and available for use
    } else {
        // Braintree could not be initialized, check errors and try again
        // This is usually a result of a network connectivity error
    }
 }} );
```

If anyone has any idea about that then please suggest here.

I am stuck with `Braintree API`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that your use case does not fit for the Drop-in UI.

In order to add a `PaymentMethodNonce` listener, once `Braintree` is setup, simply call `Braintree.addListener` and supply a `Braintree.PaymentMethodNonceListener` implementation. I've included an example below. You can also refer to the [client side integration](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/android+ruby/guides/credit-cards#client-side-integration) section in the Credit Cards guide in Braintree's documentation.

```
Braintree.setup (this, CLIENT_TOKEN_FROM_SERVER, new Braintree.BraintreeSetupFinishedListener () {
    @Override
    public void onBraintreeSetupFinished ( boolean setupSuccessful, Braintree braintree, String errorMessage, Exception exception) {
        if (setupSuccessful) {
            // braintree is now setup and available for use
            braintree.addListener(new Braintree.PaymentMethodNonceListener() {
                public void onPaymentMethodNonce(String paymentMethodNonce) {
                    // Communicate the nonce to your server
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Braintree could not be initialized, check errors and try again
            // This is usually a result of a network connectivity error
        }
    }
});
```